# oracle format mask returning decimal places

Tags: sql, oracle

I ve got problem with decimal places with my select .
I would like to get odds in format 10.50, 1.53, 1.004, 1200.00

```
select to_char(1.004,'9999.00') from dual;
```

from this select i get 1.00 but i need 1.004 .

```
SELECT rtrim(to_char(10.51, '9999.999'), '0') FROM DUAL;
```

from this i get ok (10.51) for odds where last number is not 0.But when odd is 10.50 i get 10.5 which i dont want i need at least two decimal places after dot.

Is there possibility to get round at 2 decimal places but when i get number with 3 to show 3 decimal places..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to remove the last character only if it is a zero:

```
regexp_replace(to_char(<value>, '9999.999'), '0$', null)
```

Demo:

```
with your_table (odds) as (
  select 10.50 from dual
  union all select 1.53 from dual
  union all select 1.004 from dual
  union all select 1200.00 from dual
)
select odds, regexp_replace(to_char(odds, '9999.999'), '0$', null) as formatted
from your_table;

      ODDS FORMATTED
---------- ---------
      10.5    10.50  
      1.53     1.53  
     1.004     1.004 
      1200  1200.00
```

You could use normal string funcitons like `instr` and `substr` but it gets a bit messy here.

Or you could use a case expression to decide which format model to use:

```
to_char(<value>,
  case when <value> = trunc(<value>, 2) then '9999.99'
       else '9999.999' end)
```

or

```
case when <value> = trunc(<value>, 2) then to_char(<value>, '9999.99')
     else to_char(<value>, '9999.999') end
```

or some variant of that (e.g. deciding just now many 9s to include).

Demo:

```
with your_table (odds) as (
  select 10.50 from dual
  union all select 1.53 from dual
  union all select 1.004 from dual
  union all select 1200.00 from dual
)
select odds,
  case when odds = trunc(odds, 2) then to_char(odds, '9999.99')
       else to_char(odds, '9999.999')
  end as formatted
from your_table;

      ODDS FORMATTED
---------- ---------
      10.5    10.50 
      1.53     1.53 
     1.004     1.004
      1200  1200.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select to_char(12.5, rtrim(lpad(' ',length(trunc(12.5))+1, '9'))||'.'||rtrim(lpad(' ', case when length(12.5 - trunc(12.5)) <= 2 Then 3 else length(12.5 - trunc(12.5)) end, '0'))) from dual
```

Note: change 12.5 to any number. it will return as per your requirement